How to group actions on a custom QGIS toolbar
I've written a custom plugin for QGIS that has several actions. I can add them separately to my custom toolbar but as the plugin grows I'd like to group several of them together in a dropdown that behaves similarly to the built in "Deselect Features" or "Measure" tools, where the tools are in a single dropdown icon on the toolbar and the last used tool's icon is shown. How can this be achieved using python?

Here is a minimal example that can run in QGIS Python Console and show the basics to build a menu in a Qaction and add it to a ToolBar. Hope it's enough for you to understand the logic.
toolbar = QToolBar()
action = QAction(QIcon(":images/themes/default/mIconTiledSceneLayer.svg"),"Action!", iface.mainWindow())
menu = QMenu(iface.mainWindow())

sub_actions = [
    (QIcon(":images/themes/default/mIconTiledSceneLayer.svg"), 'Sub-action 1'),
    (QIcon(":images/themes/default/mIconTiledSceneLayer.svg"), 'Sub-action 2'), 
]

for sub_action_def in sub_actions:
    icon, lib = sub_action_def[0], sub_action_def[1]
    sub_action = QAction(icon, lib, iface.mainWindow())
    menu.addAction(sub_action)

action.setMenu(menu)
toolbar.addAction(action)
toolbar.show()


Here is code for an Edit Toolbar that resembles ArcMap.
It (partially) looks like this.
